# Is there a way to alter the edge opacity in Python igraph?

Tags: python, igraph, opacity

I know that you can adjust a graphs overall opacity in the plot function (opacity = (0 to 1)), but I cannot find anything in the manual or online searches that speak of altering the edge opacity (or transparency)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edge opacity can be altered with the `color` attribute of the edge or with the `edge_color` keyword argument of `plot()`. The colors that you specify there are passed through the `color_name_to_rgba` function so you can use anything that `color_name_to_rgba` understands there; the easiest is probably an `(R, G, B, A)` tuple or the standard HTML `#rrggbbaa` syntax, where `A` is the opacity. Unfortunately this is not documented well but I'll fix it in the next release.

Comment: Ahh, I came across rgba but did not know that 'a' controlled the opacity.  Perfect, thanks again Tamás!
g.es['color']="rgba(1,1,1,0.1)" worked nicely for me.

Comment: For future reference: `a` stands for `alpha`, referring to the alpha channel which is used in alpha compositing (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing) to produce transparency effects.